# Wrong matrix multiplication causes number of elements not being the same

Tags: matlab, matrix, numbers, element

I have this matrix

```
mpsim =

   1.0e+04 *

   -2.2331
   -0.4261
    1.3810
    3.1880
    4.9951
    6.8022
    8.6092
```

this matrix

```
fvsim =

       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
         0         0    0.9000    0.1000         0         0         0
         0         0         0    0.7500         0    0.2500         0
         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000         0
         0         0         0         0    0.5000         0    0.5000
         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000
```

and this matrix

```
lingsim =

     3
     3
     3
     3
     3
     3
     3
     3
     3
     3
     4
     4
     4
     4
     6
     5
     6
     7
     7
```

I'm trying to use this code but got an error

```
sizeA=size(mpsim,1);
sizeB=size(fvsim,1);
sizeC=size(lingsim,1);
outputsim = zeros(size(lingsim));
for i=1:sizeC
    if lingsim(i)<=sizeB
        outputsim(i)=sum(mpsim * fvsim(lingsim(i), :)); 
    else 
        outputsim(i)=lingsim(i);
    end
end
outputsim
```

> ```
> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
>
> Error in ftskutes (line 131)
>         outputsim(i)=sum(mpsim * fvsim(lingsim(i), :));
> ```

How to fix this? Actually I'm assuming that `sum(mpsim * fvsim(lingsim(i), :));` is 1x1 but when I try to check it is  1x7.

Comment: It depends on what you want to calculate. Dot product, outer product or  elementwise product.

Comment: I want to calculate the inner product of two vectors in matrix

Comment: Using `dot` is the easiest way yo be sure to calculate an inner product as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that sum() only works in one dimension - so `mpsim * fvsim(lingsim(i), :)` produces a 7x7 matrix where it then takes the column sums of, resuling in a 1x7 vector.

To get the sum of all elements, you can use

```
if lingsim(i)<=sizeB
    outputsim(i)=sum(sum(mpsim * fvsim(lingsim(i), :))); 
else
```

edit:
i assumed you did take the outer product on purpose. If however you wanted to multiply each element with each other, you have to replace * with .* and transpose one of the two vectors:

```
outputsim(i)=sum(mpsim' .* fvsim(lingsim(i), :));
```

Comment: there is no error, but the output seems wrong outputsim =

   1.0e+05 *

    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
    2.2316
,with actuall output that i need like this =
   1.0e+04 *

    1.5617
    1.5617
    1.5617
    1.5617
    1.5617
    1.5617
    1.5617
    1.5617
    1.5617
    1.5617
    4.0916
    4.0916
    4.0916
    4.0916
    6.8022
    6.8022
    6.8022
    8.6092
    8.6092

Comment: To replace the temporal variable: `sum(sum(A))`

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply to vectors, you should be sure to perform the operation you want:

- Outer product: `(n x 1) * (1 x n) == (n x n)`
- Inner (dot) product: `(1 x n) * (n x 1) == (1 x 1)`
- Elementwise product: `(n x 1) .* (n x 1) == (n x 1)`

`mpsim` is column vector, i.e. `n x 1`, and `fvsim(lingsim(i), :)` is a row vector, i.e. `1 x n`. Therefore you are calculating the *outer product*.

If this not what you want, you can take the transpose (`.'`) or the builtin function `dot` to calculate the dot product independent of the orientation of your vectors.